# Login Page Logo and Site Icon with Project Config

Tags: control-panel, projectconfig

How does one configure the rebrand options (Login Page Logo and Site Icon) with project config enabled? The fields to upload these files usually appear under *Settings > General*. This is only visible on environments where [`allowAdminChanges`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#allowadminchanges) is set to `true`. How does one configure these on production environments where `'allowAdminChanges' => false` is the norm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System Settings don't support rebranding via Project Sync, however if you place your assets in the following locations and commit to GIT you can get similar results.

```
Login Page Logo -> <project_root>/storage/rebrand/logo/<filename>.svg
Site Icon -> <project_root>/storage/rebrand/icon/<filename>.svg
```

By placing the images in the above locations the system will automatically detect them. You should then see them show up in the backend without needing to upload them also.

Comment: Here's the Github issue about it: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1064